# AngularJs chaining an undefined ajax request and output progress (also if one request fail)

Tags: angularjs

I need to chain a lot of ajax requests. I'm trying to grab data from different resource and then merge responses all together. I also want to show a progress status notification of the requests.

So I have this code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http,$q) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.progress = '';
var promises = [];

var myData = {};
var urls =['data.json','data2.json','error.json','data3.json'];
var responses =['First call','Second call','Third call','Fourh call'];


for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  var promise = $http.get(urls[i]).then(function(result){ 
    $scope.progress = responses[i]; 
    $scope.pr = result.data;
    console.log(result.data)}); 
  promises.push(promise); 
}


$q.all(promises).then(function(values){
    console.log(values)
},function(error){
    console.log(error.data)
})


});
```

[PLUNKER]

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tv5XbdPSUJVNu18nv75l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$q.all` to get all response and then process the response at the same time

```
$q.all(promises).then(function (values) {
    //process all result together
});
```

And you can also plugin a callback function to each promises to indicate the progress

```
$q.all(promises[0].then(callback), promises[1].then(callback), ...).then(function (values) {
    //process all result together
});
```

Comment: @Tropicalista you can get result for each call from the call back

Comment: It's a bit obscure to me how promise works, could you give some example code?

Comment: In the end I don't know how many promises there will be, so I cannot accept your solution, but it gives me some input! I've updated my plunkr, but cannot understand how can I show a progress message after each request